# Criação utilizadores Active Directory usando forms

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Estou a criar um formulário para que seja criado na AD um utilizador com os campos em causa, mas neste momento está a dar-me o seguinte erro:

> New-ADUser : O servidor não está disponível para processar o pedido
>   At D:\Scripts\CreateUsersAD\CreateUserAD_v2.ps1:191 char:5
>   +     New-ADUser $name -OtherAttributes @{
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=8888,CN=User...MIN-  SAUDE,DC=PT:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : O servidor não está disponível para processar o pedido,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/scripting/Creating-a-Custom-Input-Box?view=powershell-6 Esse artigo mostra como imputar dados via formulário no powershell se é isso oque você procura.